# Geofire query and filter some data (server-side) to limit bandwidth usage

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I would like to know if I used Geofire correctly. My big problem is bandwidth usage with Firebase and this Geoquery.
In my app, I would like to collect in a radius of xxKm all the "demandes".
With this geoquery, all the keys can be retrieved easily. I have now all the "demandes" in this area (they have the same key as my geofire elements). Cool (1500 items).
Now I would like to collect and send to the user ONLY the "demandes" where "date1" startAt "19-09-2016" and endAt "27-09-2016". (only 3 items of this 1500) OR just all the demandes where "date1" startAt "19-09-2016" will be enough
Query Didn't filter ...

```
firebase.database().ref('demandes').child(key).orderByChild("date1").
startAt('19-09-2016').endAt('24-09-2016');
```

with this rules

```
"demandes": {
    "$the_key": {
        ".indexOn": ["date1"]
     } ,
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".indexOn": ["date1"]
}
```

I can easily filter client side all this data but is there a way to save bandwidth and do a simple filter server side (to save bandwidth usage).

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('geofire_demandes');
var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
     center: [$scope.choice.lat, $scope.choice.lng],
     radius: $scope.data.rayon //kilometers
});


var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {

    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('demandes').child(key).orderByChild("date1").startAt('19-09-2016').endAt('24-09-2016');
    rootRef.once("value", function(messageSnapshot) {
    $scope.all_good_datas = ...
    });

});
```

Is there an easy way to relieve this data correctly without loading all the data / And save bandwidth and money :)
Thank you for all your advices.

Comment: I had this requirement in my recent project, but sadly, it cannot be done. Since Geofire gives you only keys, you have no way of knowing which keys meet any filter criteria. I ended up doing the filtering client-side. If you must use geo-spatial searching and filtering (while getting only exact matches), then Algolia or Elasticsearch is the way to go.